# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have encountered a type problem using pandas groupby object.

```
    #define a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar','foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],\
               'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',\
                       'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],\
                'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8)})

    print df


    #define a function applied to chunks of Groupedby Object
    def compute_displacement(df):
        return df.diff(periods=1)

    #If I apply this function onto groupby object like this
    grouped=df.groupby(['A','B'])['C','D']
    hi=grouped.apply(compute_displacement)
```

I will get error like this:

```
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

My thinking is that there are only strings in index ,namely column A and column B, are they supposed to be not involved in the computation of compute_displacement function? How can I solve this

Solved. This is a version problem which occurs in version 0.12, but do not exist in version 0.14

Comment: I get `KeyError: ('C', 'D')` running your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing multiple columns in pandas you need to use double brackets, like this.

```
grouped=df.groupby(['A','B'])[['C','D']]
```

Comment: It seems to be that in this case single bracket works also @chrisb

Comment: you are right. I have reconsidered your answer. That was a version problem. I am still using 0.12 which brings this bug and in version 0.12 single bracker can also be used. Thank you